# Is it possible to export sides of an object as separate vector files?

Tags: uv

I have very little experience with blender, but I'm hoping that a 3D model will help. I am designing a basketball for production where each section will have a pattern (not pictured yet). I need simple flat vectors of each section to export, is that possible on blender? much appreciated <3 [image]

I basically need something like this:
[image]

Comment: Unwrap the ball spherically using seams end export UVs perhaps?

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth yeah i agree,  i think that is the proper solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//EDIT: After all this extensive answer I forgot to answer the simple question you asked in the title: yes, you can export the UV layout in a vector file, from the top menu of the *UV Editor* go to *UV* > *Export UV Layout* and there you can choose either SVG or EPS instead of PNG. The only uncomfortable thing is, when using SVG each face is a single object if you open it in e.g. Illustrator. Using EPS results in each face being a single object and the edges being separate objects as well.

[image]

If you have a basketball you can mark all boundary edges around those 8 sections as seams by selecting them and either right-click (only if you are in *Edge Select* mode) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and then choose *Mark Seam* from the context menu. Now the seams are shown in red.

[image: section boundaries]

The following steps are starting with the premise that you might not know the correct dimensions of the sections and want to get them from the UV map:

First select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap* (just the default unwrapping, no special settings). By default, the *Unwrap* settings should be *Angle-based* and *Correct Aspect* enabled, this is okay. A minimal *Margin* won't matter much as well.

[image: first unwrap]

Depending on your mesh your UV map might of course look different but my next steps can easily be transferred to other UVs as well. I want to find out how the aspect ratio between width and height of a section is.

To do that I make sure that the *UV Editor* is in *Vertex Select* mode and *UV Sync Selection* is disabled. On the UVs of left-most section I select the vertex which is farthest to the right. On the UV map, the X direction is to the right and Y direction to the top. A map starts at the bottom left with (0, 0) and goes to the top right at (1, 1). So I know since a section fills half the height of the map that it is 0.5 Y direction. The X and Y values of the selected vertex you can readout in the *Image* tab of the sidebar panel which you bring up with <kbd>N</kbd>. I want the X value to determine the width of the section, in this case it's 0.135 wide.

[image: UV dimensions]

What I now try to do is create an image texture where all 8 sections are placed next to each other. Let's say I want a texture with a height of 1000 pixels, which is 2000 × 0.5, the UV height. For the texture width in pixels I need to multiply the factor 2000 with the UV width and the number of sections, i.e. 2000 × 0.135 × 8 = 2160.

Next I create a new material for the basketball (or take an existing one, whatever fits your model). The crucial thing here is, you need an *Image Texture* node. Click on the *New* button to add a new image, set *Width* = 2160 and *Height* = 1000 and click *OK*.

[image: new image texture]

With the *Image Texture* node selected (it doesn't have to be connected to anything in the material, it only needs to be selected) you select all of your mesh again with <kbd>A</kbd> and unwrap it again with <kbd>U</kbd>. Now this might look incorrect at first because with the *Image Texture* node selected, the UVs are created according to the non-square image. And if there is no image selected in the *UV Editor* the UVs are squeezed to fit the 1:1 aspect ratio.

[image: squeezed UVs]

But as soon as you open the newly created image with the correct aspect ratio in the *UV Editor*, the sections have their correct size as well.

[image: correct UVs]

Comment: Thank you SO much!! This was an incredible and thorough explanation and exactly what I was looking for! You are too kind for including the screenshots and details. Have an amazing day

Comment: Glad I could help. You might consider accepting the answer then...?